# Error in my Makefile when using seq in a for loop

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following Makefile:

```
MYVAR = 10

target:
    for i in $(seq 0 $MYVAR)
    do
        echo "test" . $i
    done
```

Basically what I want to get is ...

```
test 1
test 2
...
test n
```

When I try to run it, I get:

for i in
syntax error: unexpected end of file

What is the correct magic for this?

Comment: `make` replaces each and every `$(...)` it is encountering in a file with the variable contents or the empty string if the variable is undefined, so your `$(seq ` looks like an undefined variable to make and thus is eaten silently. What you want is a `$$` escape sequence which make replaces only with a single `$`, which is the put out to the shell process, i.e. `$$(seq`. Moreover, make places all single lines into separate shell processes, so you need to continue your lines with a `\\`at the end so that one shell gets to see the entire loop in one piece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
MYVAR = 10

target:
    for i in $$(seq 0 $(MYVAR)); \
    do \
        echo "test" . $$i; \
    done
```

which runs like:

```
$ make
for i in $(seq 0 10); \
do \
    echo "test" . $i; \
done
test . 0
test . 1
test . 2
test . 3
test . 4
test . 5
test . 6
test . 7
test . 8
test . 9
test . 10
```

(I am not sure what you mean by the `.` in the `echo` command, if its not a typo).

Note principally that within a shell command in a recipe, any `$...` that you
intend to be expanded by the shell must be escaped as `$$...` so that it is
not expanded by `make` itself.